# How can I add a pandas column that returns TRUE or 1 if either or both the previous columns are 0?

Tags: python, pandas

**Short version:** How do I create a dataframe column that returns 1 if either of two other columns is zero (ie it returns 1 only if both are above 0)?

**Longer version:**

[image: dataframe]

I keep a close eye each month on inactive customers - defined as those who made no payments at all in the previous month. Why do we have more or less inactive customers this month than we had last month? How many declared inactive a month ago are now active and vice versa?

I have prepared a dataframe as above that includes all payments from existing customers that month and each of the last two months. What I would like to do next is have a column flagging the ones who have gone either or both of the previous and the current month without payment. I can then exclude all the ones who made payments in both months.

It's not enough to add the two months together because we review every month and:

- the ones with no payments last month who have made payments this month will reduce the sum total of inactivity compared to last month
- the ones with no payments this month who made payments last month will increase it; and
- those who made no payments in either month will be included in both months' totals but won't reduce or increase it compared to last month

I tried this code:

```
def categorise(row):  
        if row['Current_Month'] > 0 | row['Prior_Month'] > 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

pivot2['Inactive_Either'] = 0
pivot2['Inactive_Either'] = pivot2['Inactive_Either'].astype(float)
pivot2['Inactive_Either'] = pivot.apply(lambda row: categorise(row), axis=1)
```

But the final line keeps returning the error 'Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]'. The penultimate line converting Inactive_Either from an int to a float does not seem to have helped.

Any suggestions, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use comparison to 0 (=0) for your two columns and aggregate with `any` to have `True` if any is 0:

```
df['Inactive_Either'] = df[['Prior_Month', 'Current_Month']].eq(0).any(axis=1)#.astype(int)
```

*NB. This gives you a boolean column. For 0/1 uncomment the `astype(int)`.*